# Consecutive working days in JS by timestamps array

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I have the following array:

```
var dates = ["1496703600", "1496790000", "1496876400", "1496962800", "1497222000", "1497308400", "1497394800", "1497481200", "1497567600", "1497826800", "1497913200"];
```

Is it possible to check if these timestamps are 10 or more consecutive WORKING days (Monday to Friday) and return an alert if so?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question should include an attempt at what you're trying to do. Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You might start by counting that there are at least 10 values, then convert them to Dates and see if they are no more than 2 days apart and *getDay* returns a value from 1 to 5 inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Since these time-stamps are a amount of seconds and a day has 864000 of them, you could use that information to determine if your hypotheses is true.

First sort the array, then check if the difference between consecutive days is smaller then 86400 seconds with a loop.

Comment: "*Since time-stamps are a amount of seconds…*" while that appears to be true for the OP, it's not necessarily true. A timestamp is any value that represents a date and/or time.

Comment: I know, but for the sake of solving the OP's problem it seemed me to be the easiest way to explain the solution.